# Laravel login by Mac address

Tags: laravel, security, authentication

I have a website panel I want to login only from my Pc that valid email and password. If I try to login valid email and password from another Pc dose't login. I want to register by Mac address and login mac address.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The MAC address is only used on a local network; it is not transmitted over the Internet. Nor is it exposed to web applications.

Comment: there have no way , only access my panel form my pc??